# How can I change my listener in the jemeter to pass even if the response returns error code 40003

Tags: jmeter

My application returns the error code 40003 when a I try to signin indicating that user already exists, but this is desirable for my application. So, I do not want to see my listener failing in red. Is it possible to write something that converts the listener response to green even if response code is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and check `Ignore Status` box.

You can also add an extra check to ensure that response code is `40003`like

[image: Response Assertion]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more information on conditionally setting requests and responses status using [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions).